# Java, определение "полиморфизм"

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

Понял что не могу нормально дать определение полиморфизму. Погуглил, определений нашёл много но даются тяжело. Составил дилетантское своё, но не уверен что оно верное и полное. Прошу дополнить и исправить если оно неверно, т.к скорее всего я суть вопроса до конца еще не понял.

> Полиморфизм - это подход при котором в переменной, имеющей тип родителя, допускается хранение ссылки на его потомка. Соответственно допускается использование потомка там где по сигнатуре ожидается родитель, причём в случае "подмены" при попытке вызова какого - либо метода у родителя будет вызван метод потомка. Таким образом полиморфизм позволяет абстрагироваться от конкретных реализаций методов.

Суть в том чтобы дать определение без примеров.

Comment: Полиморфи́зм — возможность объектов с одинаковой спецификацией иметь различную реализацию?)

Comment: Хорошее определение, но как по мне слишком "общее", поймите правильно.

Comment: Смысл полиморфизма в том, чтобы иметь возможность создавать функции (или методы — это функции класса) с одним и тем же именем, но разными входящими параметрами и типами данных.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прежде всего хотелось бы отметить, что полиморфизм одна из трех основных парадигм ООП(наследование, инкапсуляция я полиморфизм). Второе - это то, что полиморфизм является базой для всех GoF паттернов проектирования, т.е. практически все они так или иначе строятся на нем.

К сожалению без примеров автору этого вопроса без примеров будет все намного сложнее понять... Поэтому для начала представлю простой пример, того что он ин из себя представляет:

```
abstract class Figure {

    ...

    abstract void move();

    ...

}

class Cube extends Figure {

    @Override
    public void move(){
        // moving
    }

}

class Line extends Figure {

    @Override
    public void move(){
        // moving
    }

}

enum TypeFigure {
    CUBE,
    LINE
}

...

List<Figure> figures = new LinkedList<>;
while (true) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int typeFigures = { TypeFigure.CUBE, TypeFigure.LINE };
    switch (random.nextInt(typeFigures.length)) {
         case TypeFigure.CUBE:
              Cube cube = new Cube();
              cube.move();
              figures.add(cube);
              break; 
         case TypeFigure.LINE:
              Line line = new Line();
              line.move();
              figures.add(line);
    }
}
```

Здесь приведен небольшой фрагмент игры в тетрис, в котором в бесконечном цикле генерируется случайная фигура и перемещается. Суть здесь заключается в следующем у нас есть разные типы фигур, которые двигаются и вращаются по разному, но нам их нужно хранить вместе, чтобы потом удалять(не было реализовано).

Для этого и был применен полиморфизм, мы создаем абстрактный класс `Figure` с абстрактным методом перемещения, а уже его потомки с которыми мы будем работать сами выбирают как это перемещение им реализовать...

"Таким образом полиморфизм позволяет абстрагироваться от конкретных реализаций методов." - другими словами полиморфизм позволяет делать код менее связанным, либо Grasp паттерн "Indirection". Перейдем к примеру.

```
  class A {

      private B b = new B();

      public void foo() {
         b.bar();
      }       

  } 

  class B {

      public void bar() {
         //
      }   

  }
```

В данном примере класс `А` зависит от класса `В`, но казалось бы, что в этом плохого. А теперь представьте, что вы работаете в компании и разрабатываете крупную систему. И вот в один момент приходит программист "Вася" и говорит вам: "Слушай дай мне класс `А`, я буду его использовать", в ответ на его вопрос он получит ответ в плане того, что для того чтобы использовать класс `А`, ему придется еще и брать класс `В`(а класс `В` может зависеть еще от кучи классов). Тем самым код нельзя переиспользовать другим программистам, да и вам самим в других проектах или подобных ситуациях. А теперь как это должно выглядеть.

```
 class A {

      // Inject with Spring
      private B b;

      public void foo() {
         b.bar();
      }       

  } 

  interface B {

      void bar();

  }

  class BImpl implements B {

      public void bar() {
         //
      }   

  }
```

И вот теперь когда к вам придет программист "Вася" и скажет тоже самое, он смело сможет взять ваш класс `A` вместе с интерфейсом `B`(реализовав его как ему это нужно), а не тянуть все связи от класса `В`.

Comment: Первый пример хорош. А вот второй не особо раскрывает разницу, не понятно в чем разница и что нам это дает. Что в первом, что во втором случае если нам надо изменить реализацию метода bar, то придется менять его реализацию в классе B (или BImpl). К тому же еще добавляется какой-то интерфейс и теперь, если мы добавим новый метод в классе BImpl, то нам придется добавлять его и в этот интерфейс. А в первом варианте просто добавим его в класс В и все

Answer (score 1):

Термин полиморфизм можно перевести как "Много форм". К примеру: человек может работать программистом и инженером. Такую аналогию можно привести с классами и методами. Пример полиморфизма:

```
class MyClass {

private int value;

MyClass (int value){
    this.value = value;
}
void method (){ }

void method (String s){ }

private void method (int i) { }
}

class MyClassExtends extends MyClass{

private String s; 

MyClassExtends (int i, String s){
    super(i);
    this.s = s;
}

@Override
void method() { }

@Override
void method(String s) { }

 }
```

Получается в этом коде есть суперкласс MyClass и его подкласс MyClassExtends. Получается подкласс может использовать поля данного класса, если поле не private.

Здесь есть 3 метода method (). Первый не принимает параметром; второй строчку и третий int. Это называется перегрузка - часть ООП, который позволяет одному методу иметь разные формы, которые отличаются входными параметрами и реализации.

В классе MyClassExtends переопределяется версии метода method (). Переопределение - часть ООП, который позволяет подклассу (или дочернему) свою реализацию метода суперкласса.

Получается термин полиморфизм можно объяснить так:

> Полиморфизм - это возможность применения одноименных методов с одинаковыми или различными наборами параметров в одном классе или в группе классов, связанных отношением наследования.

https://o7planning.org/ru/10193/inheritance-and-polymorphism-in-java здесь вы можете дополнительно прочитать про полиморфизм.

Answer (score 0):

Полиморфизм - принцип объектно-ориентированного программирования, обеспечивающий работу метода класса-потомка, перекрывающего виртуальный метод класса-предка, при использовании интерфейса переменной класса-предка, если в переменной размещен объект класса-потомка.